# How to pass data to database in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm working on an MVC project. My requirement is to insert data to the database through a form. I've included the form inside a bootstrap modal.

My problem is, when I enter some data and click the save button, it inserts only null rows, not the entered values. Why does this happen? How do I make it to insert the real values instead of just passing nulls?

Here's the code for the modal.

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <div class="modal-content">

        <!--modal header-->

        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="actionForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Accomodation Type Name...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea name="Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Accomodation Type Description..."></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="errorDiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="actionButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is the script for the `Save Changes` button

```
<script>
   $("#actionButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "AccomodationTypes")',
            type: "post",
            data: $("actionForm").serialize()
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                debugger;
                if (response.Success) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    $(".errorDiv").html(response.Message)
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using $("actionForm").serialize() you have to bind the model to the form input controls:

```
   <input type="text"  asp-for"@Model.Name" name="Name" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Enter Accomodation Type Name..."> 
// or you can try to replace asp-for by value="@model.Name" 
         
<textarea  asp-for="@Model.Description"  name="Description" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Enter Accomodation Type Description..."></textarea>
```

or if you using older versions of MVC you can try replace your input controls with this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })   
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And you have an javascript  bug  too.  Replace

```
$("actionForm").serialize()
```

with

```
$("#actionForm").serialize()
```

or even better:

```
$("#actionForm").serializeArray()
```

Comment: When using `$("actionForm").serialize()`, is there something else I need to do using a debugger, or the "Attach to Process" option in the Debug menu, or in the console of my browser?

Comment: @KDeven  You have another bug . See my updated answer.